# How to handle multiple type error response in Retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I am having an REST Api which can give error response in multiple formats like :

**Sample 1 :**

```
{
    "error": "Value is not valid",
    "message": "Not Authorized request.",
    "status_code": 401
}
```

**Sample 2:**

```
{
  "message": "Bad request data.",
  "error": {
    "username": [
      "User doesn't exist in system"
    ]
  },
  "status_code": 400
}
```

I am parsing this response using GSON. 
Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Didn't get your question clearly. Isn't the response self explanatory?

Comment: How would I handle the error response with GSON?

Comment: are you using kotlin or java

Comment: Using Kotlin...

Comment: could you not maybe try and setting your response as Any and then doing different parses like that ?

Comment: I think you should use custom Serializer and check whether "error" field is a JsonObject or JsonArray using try...catch clause and parse all response data manually

Comment: Thanks @SzymonHaxik implemented using Deserializer.